# How to construct a B-spline from nodal point in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline

I need to work with B-spline in Matlab using its nodal point as variable of my optimization system.

So I would like to know how to obtain the B-spline from the nodal points to work with it. I need some help to start, I didn't find a lot of documentation in Matlab about it.

I know the "spline" and "ppval" functions, but it's only for cubic spline interpolation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem thanks to Levente Hunyadi's [publication](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27374-b-splines). Download functions offered and try to understand the variable needed.

Constante to define: 
k % spline order
t % knot sequence (size (t) = k + n_control_points)

% control points 
control_points = x;
control_points(2,:) = y;

X_spline; % valores de x de la spline deseada

% Obtain on B-spline curve bspline_points = bspline_deboor(k,t,control_points,X_spline);

It looks that Matlab doesn't include this function directly.